# Autosuggestion popup will not be displayed - playwright

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, playwright

Autosuggestion popup suggesting the possible page methods(for example 'locator', 'textContext' etc.) is not getting trigged on hitting 'page.' in playwright (even after hitting CTRL+SPACE). Please help me out with this.

[image: 1]

Tried to rectify. But no luck :(

Comment: Is this VSCode? I suggest tagging as such since that seems to be the primary technology here.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright ships with `.d.ts` files so you should be getting Intellisense via the JS language service.

- Reinstall VSCode, check node version is 12+.
- `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

If all else fails, you can force the type acquisition via [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig). It should not be needed in your case, but comes in
handy when you can't get VSCode to recognize type definitions. You use it like so:

```json
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": ["playwright"]
    },
    "exclude": ["**/node_modules/*"]
}
```